# SELECT if exist or INSERT and then SELECT and INSERT its foreign key to another table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

In `MySQL`, how do I `SELECT` a value if it exist in the column or `INSERT` if it dosen't and then `SELECT` the value and `INSERT` its foreign key to another table?

I have been looking for a while for an appropriate answer but got none so far that matches what I need. I'm not very good at explaining with words so I've made a visual presentation of what I need here. 
[image: requirement]

This is my form in current state. I have the query to select the existing options but how should I write the rest of the query to `INSERT` if not exists and then `SELECT` the value to `INSERT` into the second table?

```
<?php
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    $query = "SELECT team_name FROM team GROUP BY team_name ORDER BY team_name ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $team_name .= '<option value="'.$row["team_name"].'">'.$row["team_name"].'</option>';
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
   <label>Name: </label>
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
   </div>
   <label>team</label>
   <div>
      <select name="team" id="team">
         <option value="">Select/Insert team name</option>
         <?php echo $team_name; ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: select query check results, if need be run 2 inserts otherwise 1 insert

Comment: Would you kindly give an example `query`? Thank you.

Comment: What did player look like before the 'insert'?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `team_name_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
ALTER TABLE `player`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `team_name_fk` (`team_name_fk`),


--
ALTER TABLE `player`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `team_name_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`team_name_fk`) REFERENCES `team` (`team_name`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,` @Strawberry